# How do I add a filter for a relation in a GridView in Yii?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I saw this page for adding a virtual attribute: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/167/understanding-virtual-attributes-and-get-set-methods/

Model:

```
class AdGroupKeywordSearch extends AdGroupKeyword
{
  public $keyword;

  public function getKeyword() {
    return $keyword;
  }
```

View:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        [
          'attribute' => 'keyword.keyword',
```

Controller:

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new AdGroupKeywordSearch();
```

It works to display the relation, but it doesn't show a text box to enter values.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add to the search model:

```
  public function attributes()
  {
      // add related fields to searchable attributes
      return array_merge(parent::attributes(), ['keyword.keyword']);
  }
```

and

```
  public function rules() {
    return [
      [['keyword.keyword'], 'string'],
```

instead of `[['keyword'], 'string'],`

This got the text box to display. To get the search to work, I had to use in the controller (or data provider)

```
$query = AdGroupKeyword::find()->joinWith('keyword');
```

instead of

```
$query = AdGroupKeyword::find()->with('keyword');
```

and

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'keyword', $searchModel->getAttribute('keyword.keyword')]);
```

instead of

```
$query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'keyword', $searchModel->keyword]);
```

Very odd that you have to use `keyword.keyword` and cannot just use a virtual attribute like `keyword`.